# Excel - Vlookup with results filters based on closest date before

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've got 2 tables in excel, first one with total spent per customer for exact date (for some customers there are 2 or more rows ):

```
Customer_ID  Total_$   date
```

```
12334        123455   12.12.2017
14446        222222   12.12.2017 
10551        333333   12.12.2017  
10691        444444   12.12.2017  
10295        432432   12.12.2017 
10295        132432   10.12.2017 
10195        552423   22.12.2017
```

and the other one with transactions per categories:

```
Customer_ID  Category   date
```

```
12334        1         12.12.2017
14446        2         12.12.2017 
10551        4         12.12.2017  
10691        4         12.12.2017  
10295        4         12.12.2017 
10295        4         12.12.2017 
10195        4         12.12.2017
```

What I need is to match these two tables to see last transaction before the date in table 1 per each category (there are 7) for each row from table 1 and count of transactions per each category (also before date in table 1).

So for example there will be information that for 14.02.2017 client 123424 spent 1000$, bought category 1 twice and last transaction in this category happened 12.02.2017, and also bought category 2 but only once at 13.02.2017 and for the other 5 categories he had no deals (maybe it will be easier to show it in two separate tables). Of course some of transactions for customer_id from table 2 will not match rows from table 1 as they happened after the date in table 1 so it should not be visible.

Any thoughts on that? Maybe I need another tool to do it properly? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The figures and dates in your sample data do not match with the figures/dates used in your example within the post. It might be easier to understand if these were matched and maybe better if we had a chance of seeing an output data based on your sample data.

Comment: Do you have access to Access or another database?  To do this with pure Excel functions would be very complex and ugly.  Pivot tables might be an option, but use a DB for best/easy results.

Comment: @HakanERDOGAN Thanks for fast response, here is real example for 5th row from my table 1 , customer number 10295 spent 432432  $ until 12.12.2017 he had 2 transactions with categories number 4 ,last transaction in this cateogry happened 12.12.2017 , in other categories he had no transactions

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for fast response, it can be uploaded to Access only , could you give me any tips how to deal with this task after upload?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That would be great!

Comment: Which version of Excel do you own? if above 2010, I can provide pretty easy solution...

Comment: @ygaft Excel 2016

Comment: @John, I would start exploring Get&transform or PowerQuery, full outer join feature... http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/business-intelligence/doing-a-full-outer-join-in-power-query/

Comment: @ygaft thanks, worked for this issue